# Grab object from a different page but not using the load method

Tags: javascript, jquery

If a user is on `Default` for example.  Click the navigation to go to `Page2` I'd like to load the `<div>` with the id of `container` and grab a second `<div>` with the id of `includeScripts`, but obviously not load this, just capture the text contained therein.

Example of Default:

```
<div id="mainContentContainer">
    <!-- Main content container -->
</div>
```

Example of Page 2:

```
<div id="container"> 
    Page 2

</div>

<div id="includeScripts">
    Some Text here...
</div>
```

Current script looks like this:

```
$navigation = $("#primaryNavigation").delegate('ul li a', 'click', function () {

// Load the container information into the MainContainer div located on Default
$('#mainContentContainer').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #container'); 

// Load the 'includeScripts' div and grab the text

          $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            context: document.body,
            success: function () {
                console.log('success'); 
            }

    });
```

I thought maybe using the `ajax` method jQuery provides would work but apparently not.

If my question is unclear please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing... Very similar to Josiah's answer with a minor tweak

```
$.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        dataType: 'html',
        context: '#mainContentContainer',
        success: function (html) {
                console.log($(html).filter('#includeScripts').text());
                console.log($(html).filter('#includeStylesheets').text());
      }});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just create a second div on your "Default" page that you will load the text from the "includeScripts" div into, and set that div's display to none.

From there you would be have that script text available in your Default page.

Comment: This will work for sure.  However, I was looking for a more elegant solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly it should be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    dataType: 'html',
    context: '#mainContentContainer',
    success: function (html) {
        var text = $(html)
            .find('#container')
            .appendTo(this).end()
            .find('#includeScripts')
            .text();

        console.log(text);
    }
});
```